# EIGRP adjacency "forward" through DMVPN router not supporting EIGRP

Tags: cisco, vpn, multicast, eigrp

I have a Cisco 819 with 4G which is a "spoke" and has a layer 3 DMVPN connection to the "hub."

[image: Diagram]

This (C819HG-4G-V-K9) router does not support EIGRP, therefore I cannot establish adjacency to the DMVPN "hub." It is hearing eigrp hellos over the tunnel interface.

I have a router which does support EIGRP which I would like to "pass-through" the unsupported router, and establish an adjacency with the hub.

My router is connected to the vlan 1 on the 819 router and I am seeing these debug messages as a result of "debug ip packet" with access list specifying only EIGRP:

```
  Dec 30 12:37:52.849 EST: IP: s=172.22.201.162 (Vlan1), d=224.0.0.10, len 60, input feature, MCI Check(108), rtype 0, forus FALSE, sendself FALSE, mtu 0, fwdchk FALSE
  Dec 30 12:37:52.849 EST: IP: s=172.22.201.162 (Vlan1), d=224.0.0.10, len 60, unroutable
  Dec 30 12:37:56.000 EST: IP: s=10.242.244.1 (Tunnel100), d=224.0.0.10, len 60, input feature, packet consumed, MCI Check(108), rtype 0, forus FALSE, sendself FALSE, mtu 0, fwdchk FALSE
```

As you can see, the (unsupported) 819/4g router is seeing both eigrp hello multicast packets but an adjacency is not established because:

1. The hello seen on the tunnel interface is not passed through to the VLAN 1
2. The hello seen on the VLAN 1 is "unroutable" and is not forwarded onto the tunnel interface

A static route is defined for default traffic to use the ip address at the "hub" router, which I am able to ping from the CLI of the "spoke" 819/4g router.

All traffic from the EIGRP router is statically destined to the 819/4g router.

Is there a way that I can establish the EIGRP adjacency "across" the 819/4g to the DMVPN "hub", without having EIGRP running on the 4g router?

I have tried connecting the router to the WAN/gigabit interface of the 819/4g router without luck, so I thought it might work connecting it to a VLAN/switchport.

Could I add the tunnel to the VLAN so that communication on the tunnel will be heard across the VLAN?

I am not permitted to make additional configuration the the DMVPN-HUB which is running EIGRP.

Comment: Create a tunnel between the EIGRP routers.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without touching the hub router.